# How do you save Timezone inside MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, timezone

I want to create a schema in MongoDB where I can save Timezone into the MongoDB Database.
I have this as schema

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema  = new Schema({
    fullname :{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    hash_password:{
        type:String
    },
    timezone:{
        type:String,
        
    },
    created:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password,this.hash_password);
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Suppose i want to have Timezone saved in the Database. How do I include It inside the schema as well? Do I just save it as a plain string? Or what exactly?

Comment: Are you certain you need to?  In many cases storing the timestamp with no timezone and forcing it to Zulu time makes things simpler by have a single time against which you can do compares and perform periodic operations.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the time zone as string seems to be reasonable.

Storing time zone as hour/minute UTC offset lacks daylight-saving settings. Ensure the usage of [IANA Timezone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) names (i.e. no time zones name like `EST`)